# Div not centering

Tags: html, css

I have a very basic % width set of divs.  I am trying to center the element in the `<div class="media-top-center">`.

Here is the HTML and CSS code;

HTML

```
<div class="media-top-wrapper">
  <div class="media-top-left">
    Posted by <a href="<%= uploader.profilePath %>"><%= uploader.name %></a> from <a href="<%= attribution %>"><%= attribution_name %></a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-top-center">
    <div class="top-center media-card-avatar-round" style="background-image:url('<%= uploader.avatar %>');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="media-top-right">
    <div class="heart"></div>
    <div class="repost"></div>
    <div class="flag"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.media-top-wrapper{
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card-media-top-wrapper{
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.media-top-left,
.media-top-right{
  width: 36%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.media-top-center{
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-media-top-left,
.card-media-top-right{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0.5em 0.25em 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.media-top-left{
  padding-top: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}
.media-top-center{
  text-align: center;
}
.media-top-right{
  text-align: right;
}

.top-center{
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

I have centered things before with `margin: 0 auto`, pretty basic.  but in this case, it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

I am a **BIG** fan of `display: flex;`. I think you ought to look into that. Here is my favorite guide for how to center things, and the easiest way is with `display flex`.

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

It even takes you through a flow-chart-like experience to get you what you want.

So you can do something like this depending on what your criteria are, exactly:

```
.media-top-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Previous answers didn't work for me but this def did!

Answer (score 4):

Because `.top-center` is a div element has for default `display:block` then is 100% width and margin: auto has no effect. Try changing the display to adjust with the content and center:

```
.top-center {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

That works because you have on the parent `text-align:center`

Answer (score 1):

You can't center divs with `margin: 0 auto;` if you have not set width to element. Add width to `.top-center` to make it work.

```
.top-center{
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  width: 80%; /* add wanted width */
}
```